# How to use config module on main.ts file

Tags: nestjs

I have set a config module, according to https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration then how can I use it on main.ts??

nestjs version: 6.1.1

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In your `main.ts` file after you use the `NestFactory` method to create the application you can use `const configService = app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);` to get the service from the context. If you want to leave out the generics that works too. After that you use it just like you would anywhere else in your app: `configService.get('key');`

Comment: I need the configService already within the NestFactory to create my microservice app. There is an issue open for 4 years to support this, unfortunately they always lock conversations on all issues: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2343